# R not setting resolution and figure dimensions correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am trying to format an image for a publication and I cannot get the exported image to have the correct dimensions or resolution. The example below is using ggplot2, but I also seem to be unable to get the correct size and resolution with a base package plot. I've done this before without issue, but it has been a few years... any input is appreciated.

Note: I have tried this on both Mac (Catalina) and Windows (10) operating systems, since I've been having some issues recently with R on my MacOS. The output figure is the same in both OS.

```
fake.cat<-c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
fake.x<-c(1:10)
fake.y<-c(1:10)
fake.df<-data.frame(fake.cat, fake.x, fake.y)

ggplot(data=fake.df, aes(x=fake.x, y=fake.y, fill=fake.cat))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())

ggsave("test_gg.png", width=100, height=100, units="mm", dpi=300)

#actual graphic output is an image that is 416.63 mm x 416.63 mm and 72 dpi

#additional attempts below using the regular graphics saving commands
#output is the same for me as it is with ggsave(), regardless of file format

png(filename="test_png.png", width=100, height=100, units="mm", res=300)
ggplot(data=fake.df, aes(x=fake.x, y=fake.y, fill=fake.cat))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
dev.off()

jpeg(filename="test_jpg.jpeg", width=100, height=100, units="mm", res=300)
ggplot(data=fake.df, aes(x=fake.x, y=fake.y, fill=fake.cat))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
dev.off()
```

Comment: i get this result from `test_gg.png`: `magick identify -format "%[fx:w/300*25.4] by %[fx:h/300*25.4] mm\n" test_gg.png` `99.9913 by 99.9913 mm` -- how are you measuring the dimensions?

Comment: I am verifying the dimensions by opening the output image file in another software, for example Preview (MacOS) or PowerPoint (imported as an image). It's pretty visually obvious they are too big, but also the dimensions and resolution can be viewed and edited in these programs (which I suppose I could do, but you can't really go up in resolution effectively)